# text - part of the sprite or dynamically generated

Tags: 2d, sprites, fonts

I am trying to reproduce the same stamping tool as the one we found in the video game "Papers, Please".

In my case I want my users to be able to modify the text they are going to stamp. I will use a similar blocky font.

As you probably noticed in [this sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCZ1M.png), the top of the letters is clearer in order to give an effect of depth.

How should I proceed to copy the same effect? The only solution that came to mind was to create sprites for each needed letter and then include them dynamically over [my sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCZ1M.png) but there has to be a more efficient way. I suspect the author directly drew them in the sprite but I'm not sure.

[image: red stamping tool from the video game "Papers, Please"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to just render the text twice, first with the ligher color, and then with the main color but offset by a pixel down, so that only the top edges of the characters rendered with the ligher color will stay visible.

Comment: thats actually incredibly smart.  I think Im gonna do this. the simpler the better

Comment: @Majork This is a great solution, but if you're using a sprite based font, I think it's worth pointing out that you can also do the same thing in a graphics program (Photoshop, GIMP, etc) to produce a new sprite font that has the same visual effect baked in.